# Cannot explain pagespeed score difference at similar magento 1 pages

Tags: magento-1.9, pagespeed

I've got 2 almost identical pages: one for **brand**, and one for **category**.

Brand looks exactly like category, and has same number of products.

Brand page gets score 64/95, and category gets score 88/80.

There is Amasty FPC installed, and both pages are served from cache, page load time is the same: 0.4 sec.

The only difference I see at pagespeed is this:

- Brand mobile: PSI estimates this page requires **7** render-blocking round trips and 54 resources (1.2MB) to load.
- Brand desktop: PSI estimates this page requires 1 render-blocking round trips and 58 resources (1.1MB) to load.
- Category mobile: PSI estimates this page requires 1 render-blocking round trips and 59 resources (1.2MB) to load.
- Category desktop: PSI estimates this page requires 1 render-blocking round trips and 63 resources (1.4MB) to load.

Note that at mobile brand it shows 7 round trips, and 1 everywhere else. I assume this is this issue. But mobile brand and desktop brand are the same page.

All pages have the same 3 minified CSS, and 1 minified JS.

There are both links:

category: [link](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.jonathan.co.il%2F%25D7%2591%25D7%25A9%25D7%259E%25D7%2599%25D7%259D-%25D7%259C%25D7%2592%25D7%2591%25D7%25A8)

brand: [link](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.jonathan.co.il%2Fchanel)

Note that if you check the scores, load them twice, to prime the cache.

Answer (score 0):

first of all i'll give a personal advice: Doesn't take PageSpeed data "too seriously". In most of cases, it's very hard to achieve 100/100. I know that's not your goal, but i found it interesting to share. Also, i recommend [Web Page Test](https://www.webpagetest.org), whom give more detailed information if you want.

On your Brand page, you have 3 files whom are blocking page rendering. On category, you only have one. I assume that's the cause of your question.

When i needed make pages more fast, i did realocate these css/js to the bottom (or header, i don't remember the PageSpeed orientation to this), but on mobile and mainly on bad internet connections, the page rendered the information in a "ugly" way, and only after loaded the CSS/JS.

It's a personal preference, but some of my clients wanted both: A high pagespeed score and a good-looking site, even when it's loading. My solution for that was placing some "loaders" until the site was full-loaded. I never used that with magento, but is just a suggestion, as you can see [here](http://massamadrefuncional.com.br/) for example.

Hope you fix your problem, good luck!

Comment: Believe me, it's not my requirement. The goal is to get to 80, not 100. And JS/CSS are absolutely the same in all 4 cases.